# Java Rotation Animation

Tags: java, swing, graphics, rotation, bufferedimage

Programming language: Java

Ok, so I want to have a [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) that keeps rotating infinitely. I'm still pretty new at asking good question, so do bear with me.

I have a BufferedImage called arm and it is rectangular and I have an [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) that loops repaint() every 100 milliseconds
my code is:

```
public void paint(Graphics g){ 
    AffineTransform t = new AffineTransform(); 
    t.rotate(Math.toRadians(90),(a­­rm.getWidth()/2)*scale,0); 
    t.translate(300,300); 
    g.drawImage(arm,t,null);
}
```

If you're wondering I resized the image 4x bigger so the variable scale = 4. I think my error is that I'm not mapping the pivot-point correctly but I have no idea. I really need this for my game so please help I am sooooo desperate right now.

Comment: I'm so sorry! It is "What is wrong with my code."

Comment: for `Container` based on Swing use `paintComponent()` rahted than `paint()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new `AffineTransform` always has zero rotation.  You are adding a 90-degree rotation, so every frame of your animation will look the same: the image rotated 90 degrees from its normal orientation.

You need to calculate the current rotation angle.

```
// Instance variable intialized at zero.
double angle = 0.0;

// In your ActionListener timer handler increment the angle.
{
    angle += Math.toRadians(5); // 5 degrees per 100 ms = 50 degrees/second
    while (angle > 2 * Math.pi()) 
        angle -= 2 * Math.pi();  // keep angle in reasonable range.
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    // Just use the transform that's already in the graphics.
    Graphics2d g2 = (Graphics2d) g;
    g2.setToIdentity();
    // The code for your other transforms is garbled in my browser. Fill in here.
    g2.rotate(angle);
    g2.drawImage(arm, t, null);
}
```

Hope this gets you closer.

I'll add that 100 ms is pretty slow for a frame rate. The animation will look jerky.  Smooth action needs at most 30 ms or 30 frames per second.  Games that use the GPU sometimes run over 100 fps.

And you should avoid `new` when possible inside the animation loop.  It will require the garbage collector to run more frequently. This can cause a stutter in the animation.

Comment: 1+ for changing the angle in the ActionListener (presumably called in a Swing Timer). To the original poster: consider creating a bunch of images, storing them, and in the ActionListener, simply swapping images, perhaps by swapping ImageIcons in a JLabel.

Comment: thanks! I'm not the brightest at math so I sort of get angle += 5f / 180f * 3.1415926f; but thank you I'll to  my best to get it!

Comment: It's exactly the same as `Math.toRadians(5);`  I just edited this.  A circle is 2 * pi, so half a circle (180 degrees) is pi.  So one degree in radians is pi/180. You have 5 of these, so 5 * pi / 180 radians. If you want to do graphics, you must hug the math!

Comment: thanks for the advice. This is a test program so i added 100 ms but I usually use 50. Also by experience i learned that I shouldnt put the "new" in render methods.

Comment: I have a player on the screen and his arm is supposed to rotate on the end. This method is good but it rotates in the center. How would I make it rotate at the end(rotate on the image coordinate arm.getWidth()/2, 0)?

Comment: Rotation with the simple rotate command will be about the point (0,0).  So it's a surprise that it's rotating about the middle if that's what you're using.  If you have a translation in there, then it makes sense.  The translation is moving the image so it's middle is (0,0).  There is another version of rotate `g2.rotate(angle, x, y)` that has a double translation built in.  It will translate the image so that (x,y) is at (0,0), then rotate, and then move back to the original position.  It's hard to get your exact problem without more information.